# Simplified model of antenna polarization loss

Tags: polarization, antennas, radio-frequency

I need to write a very simple model to estimate the $dB$ value of the polarization loss between two antennas (in realtime).
Such antennas are common (yet identical) omnidirectional dipole antennas, the frequency they operate is 2.4 GHz.
I googled and found a pretty common formula that should work if only I can translate antenna datasheet values into formula parameters:

$$L_p = -10\log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{4R_wR_a+(R_w^2-1)(R_a^2-1)\cos2\Delta\tau}{2(R_w^2+1)(R_a^2+1)}\right)$$

Antenna datasheets reports some data but not expressed in such terms (i.e. $R_a$ and $R_w$) and I'm not that good in physics. I think that $\Delta\tau$ is the angular offset between antenna axes.
Is it correct?
What $R_w$ and $R_a$ values means?

Thnx to everyone.

Comment: [Amateur Radio might know.](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=polarization+loss)

Comment: @KeithMcClary thnx... there I found a much simpler approach from which the formula is simply: $cos(\theta)^2$ (where $\theta$ is the angle between antenna dipoles)